# Extracting coordinates and metadata from mbtiles file

Tags: coordinates, extract, mbtiles

Since .mbtiles is raster data, is there possibility to extract this data and metadata contained in file (per point) to CSV or Excel file with coordinates + this additional metadata. So to have a row with:

```
lat: 123.123 long: 456.456 metadata: "Some metadata"
```

The best I can do is load .mbtiles file to QGIS, and now I'm trying to vectorize the layer and export single dots to coordinates. Problem is that dots are actually circles that sometimes overlap, so I cannot get exact position of all the dots. Also, I miss the metadata that is in .mbtiles files.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you pls. explain more what you mean by "coordinates and metadata"? 
Since .mbtiles is also an #SQLite file there must be a SQL query to extract at least the bounding box coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

This is a onliner you probably look for (requires SQLite installed: http://www.sqlite.org/download.html):

```
% sqlite3 -header -csv world_countries.mbtiles -separator ; "select * from metadata;" > world_countries.csv
```